# Javascript Wait for Ajax Content Load

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am newbie to javascript and am writing to traverse a DOM . The page uses Checkboxes to filter results. Results are displayed using Ajax. There are 4 level of checkboxes.

Grand Parent 
     Parent 
         Child
           Grand Child .

For each level, I want the javascript to click the checkbox and WAIT for the content to load.

Right now it checks and traverses the whole DOM , but does not wait .

What I want is , that when the element is CLICKED , next function decideread() should be called only when Ajax results have been refreshed.

I have tried using setTimeOut and other delay methods, but they say it's single threaded so that won't work. Any ideas ?

for (i = 0; i < mgtNode.length; i++) {
    mgtNode[i].click();

```
for (j = 1; j < stateNode.length; j++)

{
    stateNode[j].click();
    var read = decideRead();
    if (read)

    {
        alert('we have read the data, now skip further reading below');
        stateNode[j].click(); // we have read the data, now skip further reading below.
        continue;

    }


    for (k = 0; k < inTypeNode.length; k++) {

        inTypeNode[k].click();

        var read = decideRead();

        if (read)

        {

            alert('we have read the data, now skip further reading below');

            inTypeNode[k].click();
            continue;

        }




        for (l = 0; l < jobNode.length; l++)

        {
            jobNode[l].click();

            while (true) {
                if (new Date() - startTime >= 5000) {
                    break;
                }
            }


            saveData();

            jobNode[l].click();
        }

        inTypeNode[k].click();


    }
    stateNode[j].click();

}
mgtNode[i].click();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onreadystatechange for this. Check this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Comment: I do not control the main code of the page. I am scrapping the content, so all I can do is write javascript. Ajax call is not in my control